# IntelliJ starts but cannot see it on the screen

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm on Windows 10. I have IJ Ultimate 2022.01 when I click on the icon in my start menu apparently it starts up. If I go to the task manager I can see the process and sub-processes. When I press Windows+tab keys I can see a a tile with my workspace name. Also, if right click on its icon on the task bar and select Close Window I can see the prompt dialog confirming if I want to exit.

The problem is I cannot see the IDE's UI no matter what I do. It seems that Its running but cannot see it

I tried running it from the command prompt by running `idea.bat`. I can see

```bash
[  49559]   WARN - o.j.s.VulnerabilitiesRepositoryServer - Unexpected server error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:353)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:443)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1074)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1061)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1008)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:288)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:356)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:541)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

but I'm not sure this has anything to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just hacked my way. Apparently, there was something wrong with my last opened project. This worked:

Open

```bash
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.1\options\recentProjects.xml
```

and search for `opened="true"`. I moved this to another entry in the file and started the app again.